# Disable all but the selected option into a list generated with ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

There is an ng-repeat which creates a two-level structure like this:

[image]

If is checked `List_1`, all its children will be checked also, all that checking and unchecking functionality works fine.

What I want to add is that if an element or all elements from a list is selected all the other list to be disabled and vice versa.

```
<div>
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="(key, group) in $ctrl.allLists">
            <div>
                <i ng-click="$ctrl.toggleExpanded(key, $event)"></i>
                <i ng-click="$ctrl.toggleGroup(key, $event)"></i>
                <span>{{key}}</span>
                <span></span>
            </div>
            <div ng-show="$ctrl.expanded[key]">
                <div ng-repeat="alert in group">
                    &nbsp;&nbsp;<i></i>
                    <span class="rtm-property-selector__switch">
                        <i ng-click="$ctrl.toggleAlert(alert, key)"></i>
                    </span>
                    <span>{{ alert.Name}}</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

```
toggleExpanded(key, $event) {
    this.expanded[key] = !this.expanded[key];
}
```

---

```
toggleGroup(key) {
    this.alertTypeSelected = key;
    if ( !this.group[key] || this.group[key] === 'empty' ||  this.group[key] === 'partial') {
        this.group[key] = 'all';
    } else {
        this.group[key] = 'empty';
    }
    this.toggleAlertsByGroup(key, this.group[key] === 'all');
}

toggleAlertsByGroup(groupKey, toggleTo) {
    this.allLists[groupKey].forEach(alert => {
        if(toggleTo && !alert.isSelected) { //if already in selected array
            this.selectedAlerts.push(alert);
            alert.isSelected = true;
        } else if (!toggleTo && alert.isSelected) {
            _pull(this.selectedAlerts, alert);
            alert.isSelected = false;
        }
    });
    this.updateParameters();
}
```

---

```
toggleAlert(alertBinding, key) {
    this.alertTypeSelected = key;
    this.setAlert(alertBinding);
    this.checkGroup(key);
}

setAlert(alertBinding) {
    if (this.selectedAlerts.find(a => a.AlertBindingId === alertBinding.AlertBindingId)) {
        _pull(this.selectedAlerts, alertBinding);
        alertBinding.isSelected = false;
    } else {
        this.selectedAlerts.push(alertBinding);
        alertBinding.isSelected = true;
    }
    this.updateParameters();
}

checkGroup(key) {
    const some = _some(this.allLists[key], 'isSelected');
    if (!some) {
        this.group[key] = 'empty';
    } else if (_every(this.allLists[key], 'isSelected')) {
        this.group[key] = 'all';
    } else {
        this.group[key] = 'partial';
    }
}
```

---

The above code works well for selecting/deselecting elements of group of elements from the list, I removed the css classes for better visualizing.

I have difficulties in disabling the other lists when a list is selected, I'm using [ng-disabled](https://www.w3schools.com/angular/ng_ng-disabled.asp).

I've added `ng-disabled="$ctrl.alertTypeSelected && $ctrl.alertTypeSelected !== key"`

into

`<i ng-click="$ctrl.toggleGroup(key, $event)"></i>` line, and when I inspect the elements it says the the element is disabled but I can still check elements from other lists.

Any suggestions?

Comment: It would be easy to solve if you could provide a working snippet

Comment: disabled works for <input>, <button>, <textarea>, <select>. It does nothing on <div>, <span>, <i>, etc.

Comment: Can you please provide fiddle for this. ?

Comment: I dont understand your question. Are you looking for solution to disable List 2 and List 3 check boxes  when List 1 or any of its inner check boxes are checked?